# Getting the error "Key $ must not start with '$'" in Meteor with Minimongo suddenly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I was able to do an `$addToSet` operation like this:

```js
return Calls.update({ _id: callId }, {
    $addToSet: {
      units: {
        unit: callSign,
        currentStatus: "AS",
        statusColor: "yellow",
        textColor: "black",
        assignable: false,
        assignedBy: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
        assignedOn: new Date(),
      },
    }
  }
);
```

But, when I try to update this collection like this:

```js
return Calls.update({ _id: callId, "units.unit": callSign }, {
    $set: {
      "units.$.statusColor": "#74eeea",
      "units.$.textColor": "black",
      "units.$.currentStatus": "ER",
      "units.$.enrouteBy": Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
      "units.$.enrouteOn": new Date(),
    }
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }
);
```

I get this error:

> Exception while invoking method 'call.enrouteUnit' MinimongoError: Key $ must not start with '$'

I know this is coming from the line (one if not all) in the `$set` where I'm using the `"<array>.$.<key>: <value>` format.

This has been working up till now, so not sure what's going on.

**Update:**  The issue appears to be with my use of `upsert`.  Not sure why it suddenly decided that was an issue, but seems to be.  Continuing to look at it.

Comment: I think what's happening here is a new document is being added with a field starting **$**. It is stated in the documentation not to use the `$` positional operator with upsert. Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) out.

Comment: Just curious if you found the issue here. I'm experiencing a similar issue with a meteor update

Comment: Looks like @HannahMay is right.  It is an issue with using upset with the $ as a positional operator.  I've had to re-write to first see if the document / sub-document exists, and if so, update it.  If not, then I have to us an update and insert the new sub-document instead.